# Is there a way to enable Hyper-V features on a Win 2019 EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hyper-v

I have set up a Win 2019 EC2 instance in AWS. When I navigate to enable the Hyper-V feature; I am met with an error informing me that my

> Processor does not have the required virtualization capabilities

I am using a `g4nd.4xlarge` instance type.

Comment: No, you can't really run a VM inside of a VM.

Comment: I figured as much, but haven't poked around enough in AWS to really know for sure. Thanks.